# Postgres: Using ON CONFLICT together with CASE

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to nail down the exact syntax that I should use to do an ON CONFLIC together with CASE.

I have a table (ignore `id`, it's not relevant here):

```
CREATE TABLE public.test (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    mykey integer,
    t text,
);
```

with the constraint that `mykey` must be unique

```
ALTER TABLE test
ADD CONSTRAINT test_constraint UNIQUE (mykey);
```

Lets populate it with some play entries:

```
INSERT INTO test (mykey,t) VALUES (123,'my first value');
INSERT INTO test (mykey,t) VALUES (13,'second value');
```

Now I want to craft an INSERT statment which uses an ON CONFLICT and a CASE so that: if the new value of `t` is equal to the old one, do nothing, else update.

Here's what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO test (mykey,t) VALUES (123,'a new value') 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT test_constraint 
DO CASE t
WHEN excluded.t THEN NOTHING
ELSE UPDATE SET t=excluded.t;
END;
```

I get an error message

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "case"
LINE 3: do case t
           ^
WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
```

I'm not surprised that I get an error message, because wouldn't it be amazing if I got an improvised statement right on the first try? ;-)

However, it should be possible to either do this (provided the syntax is correct), or something else to the same effect. I know how to do ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING, ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE, and CASE/WHEN/ELSE. It should be possible to use them all together.

EDIT: I'll be updating with variations that I've tried and not worked

```
INSERT INTO test (mykey,t) VALUES (123,'a new value') 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT test_constraint 
CASE t
WHEN excluded.t THEN DO NOTHING
ELSE DO UPDATE SET t=excluded.t;
END;
```

(same error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use the condition in a `WHERE` clause. `IS DISTINCT FROM` does the comparison

```
INSERT INTO test (mykey, t) 
VALUES (123,'a new value') 
    ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT test_constraint 
    DO  
       UPDATE SET t = excluded.t 
       WHERE test.t is distinct from excluded.t;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9b0171031441cb94678561bd6ade9b7c)

Comment: This works, thank you. +1 for treating the `NULL` case correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CASE like this:

```sql
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT release_auth_planting_uniq
DO UPDATE
SET
  data = EXCLUDED.data,
  modified_date = NOW(),
  status = CASE 
             WHEN release_auth.status = 'Approved'
             THEN 'Review'
             ELSE EXCLUDED.status
           END;
```